# zend framework models location and autoloading

Tags: php, zend-framework, models, zend-autoloader

I've started to document myself regarding Zend Framework as I will soon start using it in production. Everything was working fine, until I started to use and work with models :).

The default location for models, based on Zend recommendations, is `application/models/DbTable`, where all the models will be thrown in. This location forces me to name a model like `Application_Model_DbTable_Actors`. For me, this is a very long name for a model and not a easy to use one.

The directory structure that I want to obtain looks something like this:

```
application/
  models/
    actors/
      ActorsMapper.php
      Actor.php
    books/
      BooksMapper.php
      Book.php
```

etc.

So all my models will reside under the `models` directory, but grouped in their own directories.

Naming for each class should be `ActorsMapper` or `Actor` (They will both extend `Zend_Db_Table` or `Zend_Db_Row`).

I am aware of the fact that in my controllers if I instantiate a model using something like `$actors = new ActorsMapper()` I will get a `Fatal error: Class not found` and that why I'm asking for your help with this.

To solve this issue I tried to add my `models` directory to the include_path:

- first try

  added `includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models"` to application.ini

but this one doesn't even add it to the include path

- second try:

  explicitely added the path using `set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
      realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
      realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'),
      get_include_path(),
  )));`

but even if this adds that path among the included ones, the error still persists.

I've seen this naming of models in the [official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) of the `Zend_Db_Table`, but I couldn't find anything related to autoloading them.

Thank you all for any solutions.

p.s. zend framework version is 1.11.1

Comment: You need to dig into the autoloader and extend it to recognize this directory structre and namespace. Otherwise you are tied to the zend way.

Comment: ok, so it seems that this is the only way. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Framework has a build in autoloader.  It works by mapping the class name to the directory tree, so `Application_Model_Actors_Actor` will get mapped to

```
Application\
 Models\
  Actors\
   Actor.php
```

Unfortunately, you cannot change this.  The feature you are looking for is [namespacing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) but it is only supported (and is in fact one of the major features) of Zend Framework 2 which is still being developed.

Comment: thanks for your response. so there is really no other way of changing this? it is very unusable to work with models like `Application_Model_Actors_Actors` :-< maybe someone else has a solution, if not...that's it.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the only way you could make the name shorter would be to change your directory structure.

Comment: Or by extending/modifying the zend autoloader to do what you need.

Comment: You could always setup something like `\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader` for your namespace and push it into the Zend autoloader

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap then you can try this one

$loader = $this->getResourceLoader();

$loader->addResourceType('books', 'models/books', 'Model_Book');
$loader->addResourceType('actors','models/actors','Model_Actor');

I am also trying to implement this kind of implementation in a observer pattern.